# Отсутствует перевод описания ревизии

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При просмотре [ревизий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/534858/revisions) вопроса наблюдается английский текст:

```
[Edit removed during grace period]
```

Скриншот на всякий случай прилагаю:

[image: картиночка]

Comment: На сколько я могу видеть, этой строки нет на Transifex. Сделаю запрос на добавление (это займет какое–то время).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky как перевели в итоге?

Comment: @NickVolynkin по ссылке можно посмотреть :) `[Правка удалена в течении номинации ]`

Comment: @NickVolynkin `Правка удалена в течении номинации`, но можно подискутировать на эту тему.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky словарь говорит, что надо `в течение`.

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо! Поправил.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky для предложения альтернативного перевода было бы хорошо ещё пояснить, какой вообще смысл вкладывается в это сообщение. И ещё лишний пробел перед закрывающей скобкой.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky дискутируем по поводу перевода: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3279/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вау! Вариант Qwertiy очень крут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текущий перевод:

> [Свежая правка отменена]

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

> (Правка отменена во время периода неверсионируемого редактирования)