# Перевод про grace период

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, правки

Похоже недопереведена строка

[image: скриншот ошибки локализации в истории правок]

[Ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/869331/revisions)

Comment: @Vadim к конкурсу это не имеет отношения.

Comment: @alexolut Почему? Grace period это часть конкурса, которая оставляет место в истории правок вопроса.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нет. Это время за которое можно сделать правку "туда-обратно" и будет не видно, что действительно было изменено. Остаётся только этот текст.

Comment: @alexolut Тогда это имеет точно отношение к правкам.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov безусловно. Это слово даже в переводе есть :)

Answer (score 1):

В очередной раз слетел старый перевод. Применил [по-новой](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/150127680?q=key%3A0b0dee08acad5d7c8cbde8ea2de60033):

> [Свежая правка отменена]

Будет на сайте после череды обновлений.

Ранее ошибка была выявлена здесь: [Отсутствует перевод описания ревизии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3193)

Comment: что интересно, без приписки: в текст добавлено, показывалась переведенная версия

Comment: @Grundy на этом же сообщении? В таком случае, вполне допускаю ситуацию, что восстановлением перевода в Transifex дело может и не закончиться. Т.е. есть вариант наличия захардкоженной строки. Можно поискать ещё в других сообщениях, если не лень :)

Comment: то есть что-то такое было: сначала `[Свежая правка отменена]`, потом `[Edit removed during grace period]; в текст добавлено 37 символов`

Comment: @Grundy Угу. Я понял. Ну, значит, может быть хардкод. Или перевод слетел прямо в этот момент :)

Comment: А почему выбран именно такой перевод и что вообще здесь значит _grace period_?

Comment: @Aer `что вообще здесь значит grace period` — первые пять минут после публикации или внесения правки в вопрос/ответ можно редактировать это сообщение, не создавая при этом новых пунктов в истории правок. Вместо этого изменения вливаются в последнюю запись истории.

Comment: @Arhad понял, спасибо! А почему бы не перевести как-нибудь поразвернутей, упомянув этот _grace period_?

Comment: @Aer было бы неплохо, а то новичкам действительно скорее всего непонятно, о чём идёт речь.

Comment: @Arhad отлично! Тогда надо спросить в чате; может, у кого есть предложения...

Comment: @Aer [Обсуждали уже перевод.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3299/176217) Зачем начинать новый круг? Других проблем хватает на сайте.

Comment: @alexolut я не согласен с тем, что если что-то недоработанное оставили как есть, то не надо ничего менять.

Comment: @Aer в таком случае, начните с формулировки на английском языке. Опишите предложение на [mse], если будете достаточно убедительны, может быть что-то изменится.

Comment: Благодарю за совет! Попробую что-нибудь придумать.

Comment: @aer Всегда рад помочь. Обращайтесь!

Comment: Таки что в итоге?

Comment: @Suvitruf [всё хорошо в итоге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/8560/revisions)

Comment: @älёxölüt но по ссылке из вопроса нет (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/869331/revisions). Там всё ещё "[Edit removed during grace period];".

Comment: @Suvitruf так оно хардкодится на момент появления в ревизии. Такие строки уже транзифёрами нельзя перевести.

Comment: @älёxölüt ух, ясно.