# Отсутствие перевода в сообщении о замене ссылки Духом сообщества с http на https

Tags: дефект, локализация, дух-сообщества, https

Когда наш любимый [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) исправляет формат ссылок, меняя `http` на `https`, в истории вопроса он оставляет подобное сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несмотря на то, что это не особо важная информация и никто на нее внимания не обращает, если есть перевод на том сайте для переводов (не помню, что за сайт), почему бы не перевести.

**Предложения:**

`[старая ссылка] изменена на [новая ссылка]`
`Замена [старая ссылка] на [новая ссылка]`
`Изменено [старая ссылка] на [новая ссылка]`

Comment: Уже смысла нет, старые правки не обновятся, а новых таких правок не будет

Comment: @andreymal для `[свежая правка отменена]` перевод подхватился. См. мой ответ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в данном случае не подхватится, сабж не является особым типом правки

Comment: @andreymal [посмотрим](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362538/339911).

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, некоторый текст фиксируется в базе данных на момент создания редакции и не подлежит переводу обычными средствами, доступными для этого на сайте. Например, в некоторых [старых ревизиях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/534858/2) можно найти фразу:

> из текста удален 1 символ

Текущий же перевод содержит букву "ё" и именно он будет использован при новых правках. Т.е. старая строка описания ревизии уже зафиксирована как чистый текст.

С другой стороны, некоторые переводы всё же возможны, например, см. тут: [Отсутствует перевод описания ревизии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3193/176217)

В любом случае, сейчас на [traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/) строки для перевода нет, т.е. как минимум нужно закинуть удочку на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) с просьбой добавить указанные строки для перевода. Но есть вероятность, что получим отмашку из-за хардкодинга текста в ревизии, о которой я говорил в самом начале.

Закинул удочку: [Allow to translate http to https migration revision text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362538/339911)

Comment: Я не умею `закидывать удочку на MSE` и не знаю, как хорошо оформить вопрос. Если вы оформите, будет хорошо:) "некоторый текст фиксируется в базе данных на момент создания редакции и не подлежит переводу обычными средствами" - вы имеете ввиду, что этот текст в принципе не может быть переведен?

Comment: @МаксимФисман, да, скорее всего этот текст был прописан в момент замены и больше не меняется. Тем более, что замена была не стандартная, а без поднятия вопроса.